# Copy all files of a particular extension into a separate folder, retaining folder structure (recursive)

Tags: node.js, shell, copy

Simple task: I have a nested folder of arbitrary code, containing CSS files in any particular folder. I want a command that copies over those files (and only those files) into a new folder, reproducing the same folder structure that they were in.

Either a shell command or node command would be fine.

e.g. given this:

```
src/folder1/file1.css
src/folder1/... other files...
src/folder2/subfolder/file2.css
src/folder2/subfolder/X/Y/Z/file.css
src/folder3/whatever.html
src/folder4/blah.html
```

the command would generate the following:

```
dist/folder1/file1.css
dist/folder2/subfolder/file2.css
dist/folder2/subfolder/X/Y/Z/file.css
```

Any idea?

Comment: based on your comment in the answer... you can add a `bash` tag…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rsync`:

```
rsync -avm --include '*/' --include '*.css' --exclude '*' src/ dist
```

- `-a` is archive mode: recurse, preserve attributes, permissions etc
- `-m` is prune: remove directories not required for a `.css` path
- `-v` is verbose logging

Answer (score 1):

I hope that this helps you.

```sh
cd src && find . -name \*\.css -or -name \*\.html | while read src; do srcdir=$(echo "$src" | rev | cut -d'/' -f2- | rev); dstdir="../dist/$srcdir"; [ -d "$dstdir" ] || mkdir -p "$dstdir"; cp "$src" "../dist/$src"; done
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm on a bash shell on Mac, but this throws a "find: illegal option -- n" error. Will investigate.

Comment: @kei-g: can you provide the shell you use?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm on a bash too, but on linux. find on Mac might require target path, like find . -name \*\.css -or -name \*\.html